# How can I enable/force video smoothing for old FLV media?

Tags: video, mediaelement.js

I've got a site with over a decade of media, and I'm trying to drag it into the modern era with HTML5 `<video>` tags and the MediaElement.js player for compatibility. However, when I load up an .flv file in the MediaElement.js player and upscale it from its native 400x224 resolution to something that fits the page, the video is pixelated instead of smoothed (in Chrome and Firefox both).

Do I have to re-encode the video in a more modern format just to allow the pixelation to be smoothed out, or is there a setting or something I've missed?

Comment: just try placing the `<video>` tag inside a container with a CSS `max-width` property. also set `video {width:100%}` and it will expand to the width of its container (which could have a `max-width: 400px` CSS property for instance)

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear; that IS how I'm upscaling the video, but the result isn't getting smoothed.